# How to get the column index of a DataGridView through click of ContextMenu in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with 9 columns.
I have added the same `ContextMenuStrip` for all the column headers.

```
dataGridView.Columns[i].HeaderCell.ContextMenuStrip = myContextMenuStrip;
```

`myContextMenuStrip` contains a single item named Hide Column.

Now, I have an event handler for `hidecolumnClick` event and I want to find out which column header has been clicked inside the event handler?
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is sender argument? datagrid or cell? if is cell then find column of cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the `DataGridView.CellMouseDown` event. In the event handler, store the column index or show the required context menu.

Sample Code:

```
void datagridview1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        //get the RowIndex or ColumnIndex from the event argument
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have come up with another soution if u want to use the same object of ContextMenu for all the header. check it out..

Bind the CellMouseDown event on Grid-

```
dataGridView1.CellMouseDown += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellMouseDown);
```

and in cellmousedown set the value of column clicked as below -

```
int columnClicked = -1;

void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
     columnClicked = e.ColumnIndex;
}
```

now you can access the column clicked value in  context menu item clicked event as below

```
private void helloToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(columnClicked.ToString());
}
```

It is excepted u have assign the context menu to header already..

if you want i can give u the sample also..